# PHP: datetime string to json datetime for Google Chart

Tags: php, json, datetime

I've been struggling for a few days trying to convert a datetime string to a json datetime for inclusion in a Google Chart and am now looking for some help.

The format of the date I have is "2008-01-15 14:30:45" which I believe needs to be converted to Date(2008, 0, 15, 14, 30, 45) before being inserted into an array and then being converted to JSON format for a google chart.

The goal is primarily to be able to add a trendline to the graph but it would be nice to have the timescale correct too :).

Code follows.

Any help greatly appreciated.

SteveW

```
    <?php 

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    /* Your Database Name */
    $dbname = 'speedtest';

    try {
    /* Establish the database connection */
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //DOWNLOAD CHART
    $dresult = $conn->query('SELECT starttime, download FROM speeddata');

    $drows = array();
    $dtable = array();
    $dtable['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
    array('label' => 'StartTime', 'type' => 'string'), //change 'string' to datetime
    array('label' => 'Download Speed', 'type' => 'number'),

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($dresult as $d) {

      $dtemp = array();

      // the following line will be used to slice the chart
      $dtemp[] = array('v' =>  $d['starttime']); //starttime to Date(2008, 0, 15, 14, 30, 45) format?
      // Values of each slice
      $dtemp[] = array('v' => (DOUBLE) $d['download']); 
      // $temp[] = array('v' => (DOUBLE) $r['server_name']); 

      $drows[] = array('c' => $dtemp);
    }

    $dtable['rows'] = $drows;

    // convert data into JSON format
    $djsonTable = json_encode($dtable);
    //echo $djsonTable;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--Reload page on resize-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var currheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    window.onresize = function(){
        if(currheight != document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        location.replace(location.href);
        }    
    }
    </script>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(downloadChart);


    function downloadChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var ddata = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$djsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           //title: 'Speedtest Data',
           //titleposition: 'none',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: '100%',
          height: 500,
          hAxis:{title: 'Time', 
                direction:1, 
                slantedText:true, 
                slantedTextAngle:90,
                textStyle : { fontSize: 8} // or the number you want
                },
          vAxis:{title: 'Speed Mbit/s'},
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          chartArea: { top: 45, height: '40%',
                        backgroundColor: {
                        stroke: '#ccc',
                        strokeWidth: 1},

            }
            //trendlines: { 0: {color: 'green',} }    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.        


        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('download_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(ddata, options);

    }

    </script>

</head>

 <body class="site">

<main class="site-content">
    <!--this is the div that will hold the chart-->

    <div id="chart_title">Download Speed</div>
    <div id="download_chart_div"></div>
    <hr><br>


    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
echo date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime('2008-01-15 14:30:45'));
```

In your code will look like this

```
$dtemp[] = array('v' => date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime($d['starttime']));
```

Comment: That converts the string perfectly I think but where in my code to I put it?  I tried $dtemp[] = array('v' =>  $d[date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime('starttime'))]); but got nothing :(  For some reason a NULL is returned.  SteveW

Comment: Just try this $dtemp[] = array('v' =>  date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime($d['starttime']));

Comment: For some reason that gives me a blank screen, I've also tried enclosing it in quotes to no avail.

Comment: I think you must put that in an array like  $date =date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime($d['starttime']));  $exploded_date = explode(',', $date);
    $new_value = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($exploded_date); $i++): 
        array_push($new_value, $exploded_date[$i]);
    endfor;

    $dtemp[] = array('v' => $new_value);

Comment: Something like $dtemp[] = array('v' =>  array(date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime($d['$newDate']))); ?  I want to have the chart live by using the data extracted from the database that gets added to every three hours.

Comment: Do you have online example of your project?

Comment: OK getting there - that gave me a whole lot of these {"c":[{"v":["1970"," 01"," 01"," 12"," 00"," 00"]},{"v":193.48}]}]} ,  all the dates are epoch for some reason.  I'm guessing that $date =date('Y, m, d, G, i, s', strtotime($d['starttime'])); is returning a null for some reason?

Comment: It is because your query has no result. Try to display first the date and then if you fetch the date then convert it

Comment: Yeah sorted that, I think I just need to strip out the " 's and add "Date ( to the front to make it work.  Thanks for all your help, I'll post a complete answer when I figure the last bit out :)

Answer (score 0):

The following ended up doing what was required to insert a datetime extracted from a mysql database into a google chart.  I'm positive that there is a more elegant way but it works! :)

The function goes at the start of the php

```
    function JSdate($in,$type){
      if($type=='date'){
        //Dates are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/', $in, $match);
    } elseif($type=='datetime'){
        //Datetimes are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
        preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $in, $match);
    }

    $year = (int) $match[1];
    $month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // Month conversion between indexes
    $day = (int) $match[3];

    if ($type=='date'){
        return "Date($year, $month, $day)";
    } elseif ($type=='datetime'){
        $hours = (int) $match[4];
        $minutes = (int) $match[5];
        $seconds = (int) $match[6];
        return "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)";    
    }
}



  $presult = $conn->query('SELECT starttime, server_ping FROM speeddata');


  $prows = array();
  $ptable = array();
  $ptable['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
    array('label' => 'StartTime', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'Ping', 'type' => 'number'),
    //array('label' => 'Ping', 'type' => 'number')
);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($presult as $p) {

    $date = JSdate($p['starttime'],datetime);
//echo JSdate($p['starttime'],'datetime');  
    $ptemp = array();

      // the following line will be used to slice the chart+

    $new_value = array(); 
    for ($i=0; $i < count($new_value); 
    $i++): array_push($new_value, $date[$i]); 
    endfor;

    $ptemp[] = array('v' => $date); 

    $prows[] = array('c' => $ptemp);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution less complicated at your issue. I've send a JSON response in PHP thanks to JSONResponse in Symfony. The little trick I've made in PHP¨is to transform the dateTime to 'Y, m , d' format.

```
$tableTimeline = [];
    foreach ($resources as $resource)
    {
        if($this->get('platform.timeline')->computeIntervals($resource->getBusiness())[0] != null)
        array_push($tableTimeline, [
            $resource->getTechnician()->getUsername(),
            $resource->getBusiness()->getName()." (".$this->get('platform.gantt')->baseTime($resource->getBusiness())." h/s)",
            // format -> new Date(1809, 3, 26)
            date_format($this->get('platform.timeline')->computeIntervals($resource->getBusiness())[0], 'Y, m, d'),
            date_format($this->get('platform.timeline')->computeIntervals($resource->getBusiness())[1], 'Y, m, d'),
        ]);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($tableTimeline);
```

Then I retrieved the data in JS thanks to an Ajax call and modify the JSON object to an array

```
success: function (chart_values) {
                let arrayData = $.map(chart_values, function (value, index) {
                    return [value];
                });
                arrayData = changeToDate(arrayData);
                draw_chart(arrayData); // call your drawing function!
            }
```

The little trick of this code is located in the changeToDate function -> I changed the values of the 2 & 3 columns from string dates ('Y, m,d') to readable JS dates

```
 function changeToDate(arrayData) {
        arrayData.forEach(data => {
            let startDate = new Date(data[2]);
            let endDate = new Date(data[3]);
            data[2] = startDate;
            data[3] = endDate;
        });
        return arrayData;
    }
```

Then I drew the chart thanks to draw_chart function